# Loading part of form via ajax. Extra form tag. Yii2

Tags: yii2

I need load part of form by ajax, but yii2  itself added tags form. Should create html without tags Form

```
<?php $form = new \yii\widgets\ActiveForm(); ?>

<div id="cropped_image">
    <img class="image" height="<?=$size->getHeight();?>" width="<?=$size->getWidth();?>" src="<?=$imageModel->getImageUrl()?>"/>

    <div class="inline-labels">
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'x1')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'y1')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'x2')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'y2')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'w')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'h')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'image')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Result is

```
<form id="w0" action="/admin/image/create" method="post"> <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="M0NMbk9xaEhnMx5eOEArG3EuegQoPV0yXG58XX4EAwBsMSo0KTsEKQ=="> <div id="cropped_image"> <img class="image" height="631" width="946" src="/upload/image/cec8e8f39a3cdd43.jpg"/> <div class="inline-labels"> <div class="form-group field-cropform-x1 required"> <input type="hidden" id="cropform-x1" class="form-control" name="CropForm[x1]"> <div class="help-block"></div> </div> <div class="form-group field-cropform-y1 required"> <input type="hidden" id="cropform-y1" class="form-control" name="CropForm[y1]"> <div class="help-block"></div> </div> <div class="form-group field-cropform-x2 required"> <input type="hidden" id="cropform-x2" class="form-control" name="CropForm[x2]"> <div class="help-block"></div> </div> <div class="form-group field-cropform-y2 required"> <input type="hidden" id="cropform-y2" class="form-control" name="CropForm[y2]"> <div class="help-block"></div> </div> <div class="form-group field-cropform-w required"> <input type="hidden" id="cropform-w" class="form-control" name="CropForm[w]"> <div class="help-block"></div> </div> <div class="form-group field-cropform-h required"> <input type="hidden" id="cropform-h" class="form-control" name="CropForm[h]"> <div class="help-block"></div> </div> <div class="form-group field-cropform-image required"> <input type="hidden" id="cropform-image" class="form-control" name="CropForm[image]" value="cec8e8f39a3cdd43"> <div class="help-block"></div> </div> </div> </div>
```

If i add this part not by ajax - all working fine,  just one tag.

Comment: What is the problem ? You don't want the tag "<form>" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want the form tag :

```
<div id="cropped_image">
    <img class="image" height="<?=$size->getHeight();?>" width="<?=$size->getWidth();?>" src="<?=$imageModel->getImageUrl()?>"/>

    <div class="inline-labels">
        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($cropModel, 'x1') ?>
        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($cropModel, 'y1') ?>

        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($cropModel, 'x2') ?>
        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($cropModel, 'y2') ?>

        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($cropModel, 'w') ?>
        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($cropModel, 'h') ?>

        <?= Html::activeHiddenInput($cropModel, 'image') ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

And in your code the tag  don't appear. The right way :

```
<?php $form = \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<div id="cropped_image">
    <img class="image" height="<?=$size->getHeight();?>" width="<?=$size->getWidth();?>" src="<?=$imageModel->getImageUrl()?>"/>

    <div class="inline-labels">
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'x1')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'y1')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'x2')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'y2')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'w')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'h')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>

        <?= $form->field($cropModel, 'image')->hiddenInput()->label(false); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?= \yii\widgets\ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```